# google function: accessing firestore database of another project

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I would like a Google Cloud project A (project-a-id) to access the firestore data of another Google Cloud project B (project-b-id). For the same I added project A default service account viz. `project-a-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` in the IAM of project B and set the role to `Cloud Filestore Editor`.

In the cloud function of project A, I am trying to access both project A's (its own) firestore as well as project B's firestore but it keeps showing project A default database for both Apps. The code is:

```
var primaryAppConfig = {
  databaseURL: 'https://project-a-id.firebaseio.com'
};
var primaryApp = admin.initializeApp(primaryAppConfig, 'primary');
var primarydb = admin.firestore(primaryApp);

var secondaryAppConfig = {
  databaseURL: 'https://project-b-id.firebaseio.com'
};
var secondaryApp = admin.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, 'secondary');
var secondarydb = admin.firestore(secondaryApp);
```

I was under the impression if the default service account of project-a is given rights in project-b it should automatically get rights. At least I found it applicable when I am accessing google cloud storage buckets in this manner.

Is something else to be done? Thanks

Comment: *"but it keeps showing project A default database for both Apps"*.  I don't know what this means.  What specifically are you observing here?  Do you have code that reproduces the behavior you don't understand?

Comment: Try setting the `projectId` option in the app options (especially in the `secondaryAppConfig`).

Comment: @DougStevenson: what I meant by *showing same database* is: that if I console log the primarydb and secondarydb, the resulting object shows `project-id` as the same viz. project-a-id

Comment: Thanks @HiranyaJayathilaka: when I add `projectId:project-b-id` in secondaryAppConfig I get a permission error. I must mention that if I download the private key of the default service account from the project-b settings from firebase console it works by passing it as credentials in secondaryAppConfig. But fail to understand why when I set the project-a default service account in IAM of project-b it does not work.

Comment: This is the error: `Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: Sounds like `Cloud Firestore Editor` role is insufficient to access the required endpoints. Try giving is a broader set of privileges (I understand it's not a best practice, but at least it will help us understand the problem a little better). I'd say start with the `Editor` role on the project.

Comment: `Cloud Filestore Editor` is different from `Cloud Firestore Editor`. In fact, there is no `Cloud Firestore Editor` as of now... which makes me wonder if Firestore isn't included in all this. FYI I also tried `Firebase Admin` and `Firebase Rules Viewer` to no avail.

Comment: Firestore permissions are listed under the namespace `Cloud Datastore` rather than `Cloud Firestore`. The permission that was required here is `Cloud Datastore User`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a cloud-native firestore as opposed to a real-time database in project-a. However, was facing the same issue when I tried to access it from project-b.
Was able to solve it by generating a service account with access to project-a  firestore, downloading the credentials  and accessing the same from project-b with the following:

```
credential_path = "pathTo/xxxxx.json"
db = firestore.Client.from_service_account_json(credential_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create apps within current firebase project.

> Firebase Console -> Project Setting -> General -> Add App

These apps will have access to same firestore but will be deployed seperately under different subdomains(under firebaseapp.com).

Comment: OP question is about another project not application so it won't help as much.